# Tabbed Browser CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I have successfully added a WebView to windows in WPF. How can I add tabs to the browser? I have googled but have not found any good documentation for making a tabbed browser in CefSharp.

```
var settings = new CefSharp.Settings
{
     PackLoadingDisabled = true, UserAgent="MosleM 7026"
};
if (CEF.Initialize(settings))
{
    WebView view = new WebView();
    view.Address = "http://www.google.com";
    BrowserHost.Children.Add(view);
}
```

**xaml :**

```
<Grid x:Name="BrowserHost" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
     <Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `<TabControl>` with one `WebView` on each `TabItem`. I'm not sure how well it will work, but this would be the general theory of operation. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think cefSharp does not have that functionality. As Per Lundberg said, you have to add this manually. Try to add a tabcontrol and add new webcrontrols to the tabpages.

You will have issues with this line:

```
if (CEF.Initialize(settings))
```

since the initialize can only be called once by app domain.
Try to use this

```
if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
```